# A combinatorial game about split chocolate bar

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

> The chocolate bar is a rectangle $m*n$ , divided by a recess into
> single squares. Two players play the next game in turn. On each turn,
> it is allowed to pick up one square of chocolate that has not yet been
> taken, as well as squares that have not yet been taken, lying on the
> right and above (including squares, lying above in the same column and
> on the right in the same row). The one who occupies the last square
> loses. For all natural $m$ and $n$, specify which player has the winning
> strategy.

I`m trying to solve it by contradiction, assuming that the second player has a winning strategy. (The first player takes the top rightmost square and then uses second player strategy). But it seems like the wrong way.

Should I reduce it to reverse Nim game?
Or can it be solved in a simpler way?

Comment: This game is often called "Chomp," if you're looking for information on it.

Comment: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Games/chomp.html

Comment: @anomaly, Thank you. Initially, I misunderstood the problem.